# Unable to get selected value in Angular 10

Tags: angular

[image]

I am trying to get selected value but it returns `null`. If I remove form-select class, it is working fine; but, when I add that class, it returns `null`.

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <label class="form-label">Language</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-control-wrap">
              <select #selectedLang [formControl]="loginFormControl.language" 
                  (change)="storeLangVal(selectedLang.value)" name="language" 
                  class="form-select form-select-sm">
                  <option *ngFor="let lang of langList" [value]="lang.id">
                     {{lang.name}}
                  </option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    langList: langList[] = [{id: "en", name: "English"}, {id: "hi", name: "Hindi"}];
      loginForm = new FormGroup({
        userName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        language: new FormControl('en')
      })
    
    storeLangVal(language) {
        console.log(language);
      }
    get loginFormControl() {
        return this.loginForm.controls;
      }
```

Comment: what is in form-select class ?

Comment: very difficult to help you with the few details you provide (we don't know what function is returning null, at which point in the lifecycle).

The only thing I see (but maybe it's because you didn't provide all the code) is that you're missing a form on your template

Comment: Form-select class like a select2 class

Answer (score 1):

First I do not see a `formGroup` directive in your snippet. You should add a `formGroup` directive and set its value to `loginform`. On second place you have `formControl` in your select set to `loginFormControl.language`. This is not correct. You should set `formContolName` directive to `language`. Finally you should has something like this:

```
<div fromGroup="loginForm" class="form-group">
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <label class="form-label">Language</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control-wrap">
        <select #selectedLang
            formControlName="language"
            (change)="storeLangVal(selectedLang.value)"
            name="language"
            class="form-select form-select-sm"
         >
            <option *ngFor="let lang of langList" [value]="lang.id">
                {{lang.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```